# Poll based database operations with a load balanced application

Tags: synchronization, polling, load-balancing

I have a .NET Core application that is hosted as multiple load balanced instances (separate servers, obviously pointing to the same database).

I have written a service within the application that polls a table in the database every 5 seconds, each row returned with a "Pending" flag is updated with some new values and set to "Completed". There are side effects of calculating these values.

The problem is if we have 3 instances running, each one running this processor application, there is a risk of a clash, like so:

```
Instance 1 queries database
Instance 2 queries database
Instance 1 updates values
Instance 2 updates values
```

This will obviously result in the same value being processed twice, which will cause the side effects of the method to be executed twice.

To get around this, I have added an `isProcessorInstance` flag to the config, which has a default value of `false`, but is set to `true` on one of the instances. The instance then checks this value, and will only start the service if it's set to true.

This introduces a new problem: if I give Instance 1 this designation, and it goes down for whatever reason, then we don't have a processor anymore.

How can I get around this? I'm almost all out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an instance selects rows to process, it should set their state from `Pending` to `In progress at instance <n>` or something similar, so other instances won't select these rows for processing. If an instance dies, a cleanup job should reset rows that are marked as in progress at that instance to state `Pending` again.

Pseudocode sketch:

```
UPDATE ROWS SET STATE='In progress on 1' WHERE STATE='Pending'; COMMIT;
for each row in SELECT * FROM ROWS WHERE STATE='In progress on 1':
    UPDATE row SET STATE=compute_values(), STATE='Completed'; COMMIT;
```

This handles the case of a restarted instance that you mentioned in your comment nicely, because any row that wasn't completed still has state `'In progress on 1'`

Comment: I like this. The only problem I can foresee is if the processor crashes halfway through, but that could be easily navigated by querying "In Progress at Instance <n>" as well as Pending. Thanks!